# update query not working when i attach the content of text box using data reader on page load

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Code works fine when i remove the page load content. this is a form which will allow user to edit the data already present in database. i just want to let a user edit a form which he have already submitted.
This is the code:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ENCODER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd, com As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim n, d, a As Integer
Dim returnValue As Object
Dim str As String


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    str = "select * from School where RollNo=11"
    com = New SqlCommand(str, con)
    dr = com.ExecuteReader()
    con.Open()        
    If (dr.Read()) Then

        Enroll.Text = dr("RollNo").ToString()
        Name.Text = dr("Name").ToString()
        Class.Text = dr("Class").ToString()
    End If
    con.Close()
    dr.Close()

End Sub



Protected Sub Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles [Next].Click
    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "Update School SET RollNo='" & Enroll.Text & "', Name='" & Name.Text & "', Class='" & Class.Text & "'  where RollNo=11 "


        cmd.Connection = con


        con.Open()

        MsgBox("Connection is Open ! ")
        n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If n > 0 Then
            MsgBox("data inserted successfully")
        Else
            MsgBox("data insertion failed")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: AND THIS CODE ALSO WORKS FINE. IT DOESN'T GIVE ANY ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged your question with MySql but in code you use the classes for Sql Server and a connection string specific to Sql Server.
So you should clarify this point. However, in the meantime I wish to give an answer to some errors in your Page_Load event handler:

First you need to check if the call to Page_Load is a postback from other controls and avoid to reload the data from the database in that case. [See ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.80).aspx)
Second, open the connection before executing the reader

```
Dim constring  = "Data Source=ENCODER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim str = "select * from School where RollNo=11"

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Using con = new SqlConnection(conString)
        Using cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con)
            con.Open()
            Using dr = com.ExecuteReader()
                If (dr.Read()) Then
                    Enroll.Text = dr("RollNo").ToString()
                    Name.Text = dr("Name").ToString()
                    Class.Text = dr("Class").ToString()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see there are other improvements: No more global variables for connection, command and reader and [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) around the disposable objects.

If this code is really intended to run against a MySql database then you need to use the appropriate classes like MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataReader etc.. and fix the connectionstring

Comment: thanks...what i want to ask is why the database is not being UPDATED with that sql query. i tagged sql because the sql query is not working and i dont know why..

Comment: @AbuzerBCA Steve mentioned it in his answer that you have to check `if not IsPostBack then` otherelse, everytime (even if you click *next*) this code will be executed - and therefore any inputs made, will be reseted!

Comment: @AbuzerBCA the ASP.NET Life Cycle explains well what happens when you click a button. The Page_Load event is recalled BEFORE the click event of your button. If you don't protect the code in Page_Load that reloads the textboxes then, when you reach the click event, your textboxes are reverted to the original values.

Comment: @AbuzerBCA I am looking at your UPDATE code. There is a big problem there. Please  look at this link [Sql Injection explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: @Steve Thanks. so should i use parameterized queries instead?

Comment: Absolutely yes, there is no better way